# How to compare two values inside JSON Python

Tags: python, json, api, rest

```
import json
import requests

def names(threshold):
    data = requests.get("https://example.com/users/search?page={}")
    response = json.loads(data.content.decode('utf-8'))
    #print(response)
    for page in range(0, response["total_pages"]):
        page_r = requests.get("https://example.com/users/search?page={}".format(page + 1))
        page_con = json.loads(page_response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        #print(page_con)
        for i in page_con["data"]:
            if i["bottles"] > threshold:
                return(i["name"])

print(names(10))
```

wrong printout:

```
norman
```

what I expect:

```
norman
oliver
Kyle
Zaaz
Chris
Jordan
Richard
Dora
Paul
Lena
```

P.S. in json I already have 15 names
P.S.2 if I will make print(i["name"]) instead of return(I["name"]) then I will reach full list with None:

```
norman
oliver
Kyle
Zaaz
Chris
Jordan
Richard
Dora
Paul
Lena
None
```

How can I fix it? Please help

Comment: Im no python expert but usually return will only run once. So your for loop will be useless

Comment: You probably have to declare an array that you want to hold the values first and add to that array with each loop iteration. Makes sense?

Comment: @lenz is right, if you want you can save the names inside a list or a dictionary and then return the list or the dictionary

Comment: Your title and the actual problem seem to have little to do with each other

Comment: Or you could `yield` the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from what I can tell (which is very little, since the url you are working with is failing) you are trying to index into "Json" (which you are not) and you are trying to compare it's subsequent value against the value of your threshold variable.

json.loads will return a data structure that the python language can represent, this will usually be in the form of a list, or a dictionary, or a list of dictionaries, so on and so forth. But you are not checking for any of that in your code, you are just attempting to get data structures from a url and willy nilly looping through them. Since your code does not run, I used jsonplaceholder api to try and recreate your problem.

As it stands, your code is filled with some other issues as well, that I thought I might as well explain and fix. To the best of my abilities.

The python language has something called "type hints" it allows you to suggest what type of variable something is, or what type a function returns. Unlike C++ and other statically typed languages, Pythons type hints are merely suggestions, not commandants. But it helps code readability, and helps you as you are attempting to iterate through data structures. Iterating through lists, and dictionaries are completely different things. And after all you can't work with data, unless you know what structure the data is in.

Your comparison is logically wrong, and it doesn't filter out None values,
also if this particular iteration of 'i' does not have a key called 'bottles', your code blows up.

```
    if i["bottle"] > threshold:
```

would be better written in one line:

```
    # also check if i["names"] exists, it will discard None values
    if i["bottles"] <= threshold and i["name"]:
        print(i["name"])
```

```
import sys
import json
import requests


# Python is powerful, you can return different types of values
# from a single function, this arrow syntax demonstrates how to code
# that as a type hint
def names(threshold: int) -> (list or None):
    """
    Doc strings are important, a proper IDE, or a well configured Vim
    or Emacs, will show you these Doc strings when you type out a function
    name.

    :raises: NotImplementedError if API returns dictionaru
    :param: the maximum names we want?
    :return: list of only names, or None if response code is not 200
    :rtype: list or None
    """
    response: requests.Response = \
        requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")

    if not response.status_code == 200:
        # API isnt working, return None, or you could also raise
        # a different error, up to you
        return None

    data: list = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        # the api gave us back something other than a list
        # our code is borked
        raise NotImplementedError

    # make a list to hold all names in
    name_container: list = []
    # data is a list containing a dictionary basically
    for struct in data:
        # now we can iterate through the keys looking for a match
        if struct['id'] <= threshold and struct['name']:
            name_container.append(struct['name'])

    return name_container



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        names: list = names(10)
    except NotImplementedError:
        sys.stderr.write("API changed on us, uh oh\n")
        # call some other function that handles it
        sys.exit(1)


    # the function can also return None, check for that before printing
    if names:
        for name in names:
            print(name)
```